# Strange error after SQLAlchemy update: 'list' object has no attribute '_all_columns'

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Here's a simplified version of my query:

```
subquery = (select(['latitude'])
            .select_from(func.unnest(func.array_agg(Room.latitude))
                         .alias('latitude')).limit(1).as_scalar())
Room.query.with_entities(Room.building, subquery).group_by(Room.building).all()
```

When executing it I get an error deep inside SQLAlchemy:

```
  File ".../sqlalchemy/sql/selectable.py", line 429, in columns
    self._populate_column_collection()
  File ".../sqlalchemy/sql/selectable.py", line 992, in _populate_column_collection
    for col in self.element.columns._all_columns:
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '_all_columns'
```

Inspecting it in a debugger shows me this:

```
>>> self.element
<sqlalchemy.sql.functions.Function at 0x7f72d4fcae50; unnest>
>>> str(self.element)
'unnest(array_agg(rooms.id))'
>>> self.element.columns
[<sqlalchemy.sql.functions.Function at 0x7f72d4fcae50; unnest>]
```

The problem started with SQLAlchemy 0.9.4; in 0.9.3 everything worked fine.

When running it in SQLAlchemy 0.9.3 the following query is executed (as expected):

```sql
SELECT rooms.building AS rooms_building,
       (SELECT latitude
        FROM unnest(array_agg(rooms.latitude)) AS latitude
        LIMIT 1) AS anon_1
FROM rooms
GROUP BY rooms.building
```

Am I doing something wrong here or is it a bug in SQLAlchemy?

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a bug in SQLAlchemy: https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/issue/3137/decide-what-funcxyz-alias-should-do

> `func.foo().alias()` should in fact be equivalent to `func.foo().select().alias()`, however in this case that will push out a second level of nesting here which you don't want. So to make that correction to the API probably needs to be a 1.0 thing, unless I can determine that `func.foo().alias()` is totally unusable right now.

The proper way to do it, according to the SQLAlchemy developer, is this:

```
subquery = (select(['*']).select_from(
                func.unnest(func.array_agg(Room.latitude)))
            .limit(1)
            .as_scalar())
```

Most likely the next version (0.9.8 I assume) is going to have the old behavior restored:

> I'm restoring the old behavior, but for now just use `select(['*'])`. the column is unnamed. PG's behavior of assigning the column name based on the alias in the FROM is a little bit magic (e.g., if the function returned multiple columns, then it ignores that name and uses the ones the function reports?)